# NSTableView not populating any data

Tags: xcode, nstableview, populate

I am trying to set up a very basic NSTableView with one column via the example code in Apple's documentation. I am setting it up programatically as Cocoa bindings are still a little like a dark art to me at the moment, however when I Build & Run I get no data in my app. Is there something missing from my code? (I've also hooked up my datasource and delegate via Interface Builder, so it can't be that either.)

Interface file

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface RLTAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSScrollView *tableView;

@property (copy) NSArray *nameArray;

@end
```

Implementation file

```
#import "RLTAppDelegate.h"

@implementation RLTAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    _nameArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Ryan", @"Steven", @"Scott", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {

        return _nameArray.count;
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

    NSTextField *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"withoutIcon" owner:self];

    result.stringValue = [self.nameArray objectAtIndex:row];

    return result;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NStableView *tableview;
```

Comment: That seemed logical but it hasn't made a jot of difference! I'm completely confused, I have to be honest.

Comment: just check tableview delegate function call or not.

Comment: put NSLog into the numberOfRowsInTableView with the array count value.

Comment: Ah, that isn't being called. So how do I make sure it is called?

Comment: after the array data. set tableview.delegate and datasource and then reload tableview.

Comment: Should I have to do this though if I've already set the delegate and the datasource via Interface Builder?

Comment: if you confident with what you did properly means, delegate function will call.

Comment: I've hooked up my table view by Ctrl dragging to App Delegate and choosing: 'delegate' and then again for 'datasource' - that's correct?

Answer (score 0):

Connect your Outlet of tableview from xib/storyboard and dont forget to set delagate and datasource.

`@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;`

In Interface Builder, in the Attributes inspector pane (Cmd-Opt-4), set the table view type to View Based. It is Cell Based by default.

You have to select the table view in either in the left-hand object view or by clicking on it in the editor. Notice that the first time you click on it in the editor, it will select the scroll view, so you will have to click on it a second time to get it to select the table view object.

I believe you need Xcode 4.3 or newer for the OS X 10.7 SDK, and hence view-based tables views, to be available.

Comment: Yea, I added that and I've already set my app delegate as the delegate and datasource. Can't think what else I've missed here!

Comment: I changed it to view (good tip) and have clicked twice to get to the table view object. Still, when I B&R, I get nothing....

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing and it turned out that the NSTextField result was not being instantiated. I ended up using

```
NSTextField *result = [[NSTextField alloc]init];
result.string = [_nameArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

and this works just fine.